# Python number using lower case 'e' for scientific notation instead of 'E'

Tags: python, scientific-notation

I'm calculating FX rates in Python.

Doing a really simple calculation of rate = currency_1_rate/currency_2_rate (where rates for both currencies are just a decimal number), which is returning a rate in scientific notation with a lower case 'e'.

For example IDR to USD rate is being returned as: 6.87758e-05

Is there a way to get python to output these numbers/rates using a capital E for the scientific notation instead? There are processes further down the line that might not accept this lower case 'e' notation.

I am doing a pandas to_csv with these rates, so ideally don't to be converting to a string then back to a number.

Comment: If `val` is the value you want to print, you could do this: `print(f"{val:E}")` which works as a format specifier. I encourage you to learn more about these format specifiers, as they make tasks ridiculously simple later on.

Comment: Unrelatedly: You probably don't want to use floating point numbers for currency exchange rates.

Comment: @gspr You can probably drop the "probably".

Comment: I converted the input table type to be float: fx_rates = fx_rates.astype({2:'float'})

Comment: @Jerry12345678: That's a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/453616

Comment: How can I convert my table/DF into type Decimal? Or would I go float and the convert it to decimal?

Answer (score 0):

When using `.to_csv` you can supply the `float_format` parameter.
You can supply with with the `E` argument, specifing to use scientific notation with capital E.

```
df.to_csv("path/to/file.csv", float_format="E")
```

For further reading, see [Format Specification Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I need to write out this number to a CSV file and want to retain the number and not convert to a string and back to a number.

Comment: Right. That's quite a crucial detail, you should include in your question!

Comment: Updated my answer to be in relation to `to_csv`

Comment: The above float_format="E" didn't seem to work. So I wrote a really simple bit of code to check why this wasn't working. I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" - any ideas why?

Comment: import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.1111],[2.2222],[3.3333]]))
cwd = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
test = test.astype('float')
test.to_csv(cwd+'\\'+ 'test', index=False, float_format='E')